# C# real-time Cartesian chart with multiple series doesn't show up Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting library

Tags: c#, .net

During programming my .NET application, I faced a problem employing a real time cartesian chart using Datavisualization.Charting library. I need to visualize a real time change of data during a milliseconds time period. In a timer tick I declared an 'if' statement that every 60 second update maximum and minimum value of x Axis , but that's cause this problem :

When I try to set maximum and minimum value on X axis, the chart doesn't show up the y value of 4 series declared in constructor, so only time line appear in x axis and no data in y axis.

How can I solve this problem ?

This is my C# code:

```
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "H:mm:ss";

    chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;

    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = timeNow.ToOADate();
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToOADate();

    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 5;
```

that's is the upadating series in the timer tick

```
    chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(firstdata);
    chart1.Series[1].Points.Add( secondsdata);
    chart1.Series[2].Points.Add( thirddata);
    chart1.Series[3].Points.Add( fourthdata);
```

that's the code in Timer tick every 60 seconds maximum and minimum value of x axis updating dynamically

```
    if (_counter == 60)
    {
        _counter = 0;
        
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = 
        timeNow.ToOADate();
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = 
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToOADate();

        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IntervalType = 
        DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 5;

    }
```

I tried to delete maximum and minimum value of x axis so y axis series would start showing by updating the series values, but the problem is that now I can't get a good time line in x axis .net